# Android Google Maps transparent system bar causes UI controls overlap the Toolbar

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I am trying to have a Google Map under a transparent system bar. My problem is the UI controls (Compass and My Location Buttons) are obscured by the Toolbar. How do I fix this? Note that setting `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` on the Map is not the solution - it will prevent the map from drawing under the system bar.

I am making the system bar transparent by setting:

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
```

in my style.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a padding to the top of the map. For example:

```
googleMap.setPadding(0, 100, 0, 0);
```

From [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#setPadding(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) (emphasis mine):

> This method allows you to define a visible region on the map, to signal to the map that portions of the map around the edges may be obscured, by setting padding on each of the four edges of the map. Map functions will be adapted to the padding. For example, **the zoom controls, compass, copyright notices and Google logo will be moved to fit inside the defined region**, camera movements will be relative to the center of the visible region, etc.